# C# errors: declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Not too sure what went wrong, the first 2 are errors and the last one is a "warning"?

*PlayerController.Start()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial*

*The type or namespace name '_boxCollider2D' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

*'PlayerController.GetComponent()' hides inherited member 'Component.GetComponent()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.*

```
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start();
    
        _boxCollider2D  GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>(){}
```

It was already put in the start/top of the code like this, but when I try to change it, it keeps going wrong:

```
    private BoxCollider2D _boxCollider2D;
```

Comment: The syntax of this code is terribly wrong. First, the body of `Start` is meant to be written here but there are no curly braces. Second, GetComponent is a method belonging to `_boxCollider2D`, so you should use a `.` to reference it. Third, you need a `;` to complete the assignment statement and should remove the curly braces after `GetComponent`.  Overall, you should have `private void Start() { _boxCollider2D = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();}`.

Comment: Given what is your current level of expertise with c#, a q&a site such as stack overflow is not likely to help you as much as articles about C# fundamentals, tutorials, or other long-form educational material.

Comment: I second @Ruzihm's opinion. You should at a minimum read through some true beginner C# guides. There are plenty out there that give a solid understanding enough to start doing simple scripts in Unity. You will need far more knowledge to properly make a game than where you are at now and learning C# basics outside of Unity will help you focus on one thing at a time.

Answer (score 1):

The error gives you some pretty good hints!

> PlayerController.Start()' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or partial

It's saying that your method named `Start()` in your class named `PlayerController does not have a body. You've put a semicolon instead of curly braces.

This is how the method declaration should look.

```cs
// Start is called before the first frame update
private void Start()
{
    // Code here
}
```

You seem to be new to C#, so I recommend checking out some tutorials first. Here's a good introduction series: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/tutorials/